# Swift - Custom color theme and SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am applying custom colors to several views, like this:

```
 let uiView = UIView.appearance()
 uiView.backgroundColor = .black
```

This changes the UIView colors as I expected but later in the app I am triggering a SFSafariViewController. When SFSafariViewController appears it is all black. Is there a way to identify view is SFSafariViewController and change the color of it?

```
 let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: targetURL!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
 present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have a hard time going through with your approach - changing the background colour of UIView changes the background colour of every view that inherits from UIView also, which as you've found includes the whole of SFSafariViewController - buttons and all.

I'd suggest a better approach is to be more specific about which types of views you want to set the background colour for, UIButton, UITabBar and so on. If you also have actual UIViews you need to change you could make a subclass and set the appearance on that instead. Your UIView subclass can be empty:

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

}
```

And then you can set your appearance on this view:

```
MyCustomView.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
```

In Interface Builder, select your view and set your custom class for it:

[image: custom view class]

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for that.

Just use [CSafariWebKit](https://github.com/dmandarino/CSafariWebKit) and set the Color you want in BarTintColor and the TintColor:

```
let vc = SafariViewController(url: url, barTintColor: nil, tintColor: nil)
vc.presentSafari(fromViewController: self, whenDidFinish: nil)
```